# How can I get specific items from text file? Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, loops, text-files

I am trying to figure out how to get a message box to show only specific words from a text file, which contains all of the words within the dictionary. I have tried various different ways, but cannot get it to work, but I do think I am on the right track so just need some pointers.

Basically, there is a scrambled up string, which is different every time, and is contained within a label. I want the program to only show words which contains the letters inside the scrambled string, but not sure how to achieve this?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Private Sub btnAnswers_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAnswers.Click

    Dim hash As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Katie\Documents\Project\dictionary.txt"))
    Dim Letters As String
    Dim OneCharacter As String
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim item As String
    Dim AllCharacters As String

    Found = False
    Letters = lblLetters.Text

    For i = 0 To Letters.Length - 1
        OneCharacter = Letters.Substring(i, 1)
        For Each item In hash
            If item.Contains(OneCharacter) Then
                Found = True
                AllCharacters = OneCharacter
            Else
                Found = False
            End If
            MsgBox(item)
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

The message box does show up words, from the dictionary, but words can contain letters that are not present in the label string, so my code is wrong. Can anyone help? Apologies, but I am new to programming.

Comment: You need to loop through all of the words (in `hash`) in the outer loop, and then evaluate the current word against all of the search letters in an inner nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple modification to the previous answer you can restrict the output to only words that contain only the scrambled letters:

```
Private Sub btnAnswers_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim hash As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Katie\Documents\Project\dictionary.txt"))
    Dim Letters As String = lblLetters.Text
    For Each item As String In hash
        Dim word As String = item.ToLower()
        For i = 0 To Letters.Length - 1
            Dim OneCharacter As Char = Char.ToLower(Letters(i))
            While word.Contains(OneCharacter)
                word = word.Remove(word.IndexOf(OneCharacter), 1)
            End While
        Next
        If (word.Length = 0) Then
            'The given dictionary entry includes all the letters in the label. No more iterations will be performed
            MsgBox(item)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

With this code if the scrambled letters contain 'bok' then "book" will get selected.  However removing the while loop and leaving only the remove statement, will ensure that only the exact number of each different letter will match.  so that 'obok' will be needed to match "book".

Comment: More than removing, I think that what she wants is just selecting words from the dictionary where all its characters are contained by the label, that is: "dictionary" is fine if the label is "dictionary" (or "dictionayr"). This is what I understood at least. I think that I have been of help more than enough and thus will not change my answer: all for you.

Comment: From what the OP said if the label is "dictionar" she doesn't want "dictionaries", since the 'e' and the 's' aren't in the original string.

Comment: Exactly. Your code is delivering the functionality but provoking it rather than retrieving an existing entry. What I think that she wants is locating "dictionar" in the text file, if it is not there nothing will be returned. But see... this is not my problem: ask her about what she is exactly after.

Comment: It does retrieve the existing item.  If the string is short enough and more than one entry can be found matching that string then there is no way to determine which entry is the right one.  No one said it was your problem. I only gave credit for the base of the code in my answer.

Comment: Thank you @tinstaafl. I am sorry if my description isn't clear. An example of the label string could be CYUIALT and a word within that label could be "CAT" (for example) and that is a word within the text file which is called 'dictionary', as I said the text file contains all of the words in the dictionary. I wanted the program to check whether the word entered contains letters that can be found in the label string.

Comment: My code should do that.  If all the letters in a dictionary word are present in the scrambled word, the messagebox will show it.  In this case though you will probably will want to use another List to store any matching words, and/or add then to a listbox

Comment: @tinstaafl thank-you for getting this to work for me :) It works just as intended!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Steven Doggart, you have to invert the loop nesting. What you want is going through all the dictionary entries and, for each of them, checking if it contains all the letters in the string. Your loop structure is not allowing to do that.

I have performed the required updates in your code. Bear in mind that this code ignores caps ("A" is the same than "a").

```
Private Sub btnAnswers_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim hash As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Katie\Documents\Project\dictionary.txt"))
    Dim Letters As String = lblLetters.Text
    For Each item As String In hash
        Dim Found As Boolean = True
        For i = 0 To Letters.Length - 1
            Dim OneCharacter As String = Letters.Substring(i, 1)
            Dim itemToLower As String = item.ToLower()
            If Not itemToLower.Contains(OneCharacter.ToLower()) Then
                Found = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        If (Found) Then
            'The given dictionary entry includes all the letters in the label. No more iterations will be performed
            MsgBox(item)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code looks for keys containing all the characters in the given label (not at the contrary), that is: with a label "dict", "dictentry" would be right.

In any case, the whole point of my answer is not delivering a code which you just have to execute; the point of this code is helping you to understand what you did wrong and how to start doing things right. If you are not interested in this exact functionality, you woud have to edit my code such that what you want can be accomplished; or, ideally, you would be writing your own code completely from scratch.

Comment: This still brings up words that contains letters which aren't present in the label string :(

Comment: @Katie ironically I was writing right now a comment for you. I have observed that you haven't awarded a single question since you are here. To be honest with you, I don't like this attitude at all (I consider it pretty ungrateful with others who have spent their time helping you) and actually it plays against your ranking (and thus against the things you can/cannot do in the site). If you don't mind, I would like to know a bit more about this before continue answering your questions: why don't you ever award an answer?

Comment: @Katie (I am looking still for your answer to my previous question) just to clarify things: what this code looks for is a dictionary key including all the letters in the label, that is, dictionary key = "dictkey" and label = "dict"; "dictkey" is valid. If you want to get dictionary keys which only consist in the letters of the label, that is, same words but with characters, eventually, in different order ("dictkey" in the example above would be wrong); the code would have to be modified. I look forward to your answers to my two questions.

Comment: I apologise, I am very grateful and if you look at previous questions I have awarded people marks and have left comments saying that I appreciate their help. Sorry again and I will continue improving. Okay and thank-you for your help, sorry I appear ungrateful and that I have angered you.

Comment: @Katie angered me?! LOL This is impossible. I say things plainly to avoid misunderstandings, but I am not angry (at all). I am just saying what I see (and what I think): not a single question has been awarded. Also, please, take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @Katie OK, now you have awarded a question but this wasn't there a while ago :)

Comment: OK, you seemed pretty annoyed and I don't want to be seen as ungrateful. Thank-you for your time though, I really mean that and I will award you points as you have really tried to help me.

Comment: @Katie don't misunderstand me I don't care about points (perhaps in general, but for a given situation, never think about that). I said what I said, not for me; but in general. Perhaps it wasn't your intention and that's why I prefer to clarify the point (better saying things openly than doubting, don't think so?)... I apologise if my tone was too rude.

Comment: @Katie you have +1 me? it wasn't necessary. Anyway... a new question adapting mine to your requirements: all for you :)

Comment: No, I wouldn't award points if I didn't see fit, but you have helped me.

Comment: @Katie just as a farewall, I didn't "try to help you", I have actually helped you. I did misunderstand the exact functionality you are after (as anyone else here) because you haven't explained it too clearly (and your code does not deliver something even close). Once I have understood what you want (I think that now), I have decided to not edit the code because I don't think that will be of real help to you. (Ah! you weren't the upvoter! ah! weird) Anyway... go to see the new answerer, explain him exactly what you want and he will deliver it to you.

Comment: I have tried many different ways, as I have stated and put I think I am on that right track, so if I am not even close, you could have simply said that? I posted the code above as an example of what I finally had. I am new to this and all I wanted was pointers and if I didn't make sense, you could have said.

Comment: @Katie please talk with tinstaafl and explain him the exact functionalies you want because this is what he is doing (adapting my code to what you want exactly). As you can see from the differences between all our codes and yours, you weren't exactly on the right track; but you are close now, just explain the exact functionalities properly and start thinking in a more adequate way: if the codes provided are not delivering what you want is not because three (pretty-experienced, at least, one :)) developers don't know what they are doing, but because you haven't explained what you want properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `MsgBox(item)` outside of the if statement that determines whether the current word contains the current character. Which means it's going to pop up for every letter, every word. Move `MsgBox(item)` inside the first half of the if statement if you only want it to show when the letter is actually found in the word.

I'd also suggest following Steven Doggart's advice and reversing the way the loops are nested. If the characters are the outer loop, you could get the message box multiple times per word (e.g., if your letters are "sdf" and one of the words is "foods," it will pop up 3 times).

```
For Each item In hash
    For i = 0 To Letters.Length - 1
        OneCharacter = Letters.Substring(i, 1)
        If item.Contains(OneCharacter) Then
            Found = True
            AllCharacters = OneCharacter
            MsgBox(item)
        Else
            Found = False
        End If
    Next
Next
```